# global variable becoming undefined in second callback

Tags: jquery

I have a couple of variables that I declare before $(document).ready().These variables are present in a callback function that gets called x amount if times but I'm having a problem after the first callback function with some of the variables becoming undefined.

```
    var file_count = 0;
    var permission_state = [ [] ];
    var rate_info = [ [] ];
    var is_rated = [];
    $(document).ready(function(){

    ...

    onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON) {
        if($("input[name=voteit"+id+"]").prop("checked")){
            is_rated.push(1);
            rate_info[id].push($("#title-textarea"+id).val());
            rate_info[id].push($("select[name=category"+id+"]").val());
            rate_info[id].push($("select[name=subcategory"+id+"]").val());
        } else {
            is_rated.push(0);
            permission_state[id].push($(".permission-level"+id).val());
            permission_state[id].push($("#title-textarea"+id).val());
        }
    ...
```

And console gives me:

"Caught exception in 'onValidate' callback - TypeError: permission_state[id] is undefined"

id in this case is an integer that is incremented each iteration of the callback function and I've checked that it is working properly. Also why is the console not saying anything about is_rated variable to be undefined and only rate_info or permission_state?

Edit: thanks for the advice I did:

```
        onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON) {
        if($("input[name=voteit"+id+"]").prop("checked")){
            rate_info[id] = [];
            is_rated.push(1);
            rate_info[id].push($("#title-textarea"+id).val());
            rate_info[id].push($("select[name=category"+id+"]").val());
            rate_info[id].push($("select[name=subcategory"+id+"]").val());
        } else {
            permission_state[id] = [];
            is_rated.push(0);
            permission_state[id].push($(".permission-level"+id).val());
            permission_state[id].push($("#title-textarea"+id).val());
        }
    ...
```

and it worked.

Comment: Where do you create `permission_state[id]`?

Comment: The first callback: `id` is 0, `permission_state[0]` is an array. The second time: `id` becomes 1, but `permission_state` has only one element in it, so `permission_state[1]` is undefined.

Comment: You can't push something into an array that isn't defined yet. You should probably check if `permission_state[id]` is defined, and if not, set it as an array first. Something like: `permission_state[id] = permission_state[id] || [];` then do your `permission_state[id] =` lines.